# PL/SQL - Days Between two Dates

Tags: plsql

I have the below script and I want the script to display just the amount of days between the two days, essentially removing the negative sign infront of the number. Is this possible?

```
select (TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AS days 

From testtable1
```

Output is:

```
Days
 -5
 -6
    etc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT (TO_DATE('06-05-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-05-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AS "Days"
FROM DUAL;
```

The reason why this query is returning a negative value is because you are doing a calculation the other way round. Lets take the above query as an example;

Start Date -> 01-05-1994 && End Date -> 06-05-1994

01 - 06 = -5 days

Flipping the values is what you need

06 - 01 = 5 days

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use ABS:

The number to convert to an absolute value.

```
select ABS(TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AS days 

From testtable1
```

Comment: Why do you post a question, and then answer it right away yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

SELECT ROUND( TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(StartDate ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EndDate ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
FROM dual

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks